# Comparar uma string array com outra array de string e criar uma nova array

Tags: javascript, array, string

Preciso de um método/algoritmo que encontre em `array1` strings de `array2` e crie uma nova array (`array3`) com todas as stings separadas da `array2`.

**Por exemplo**

`array1 = ['azxsdfghjkazxfgtfgt'];`

A **array2** ficaria dessa forma:

`array2 = ['azx', 'sdf', 'ghjk', 'fgt'];`

Já a **array3** ficaria dessa forma:

`array3 = ['azx','sdf','ghjk', 'azx', 'fgt', 'fgt'];`

Comment: Não percebi... queres encontrar em array1 strings de array2 e adicioná-las a array2, é isso?

Comment: quero encontra em array1 strings de array2 e criar uma nova array com todas as stings separadas da array2

Comment: E quando um pedaço for encontrado ele pode ser usado para match futuro? ou é removido do algoritmo?

Comment: quando o pedaço for encontrado, ele tem q ser usado para match, sem remover nada do algorítimo

Comment: A minha pergunta é se letras desse match anterior podem ser usadas caso façam match com outras?

Comment: isso, ela pode ser usadas com outras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes percorrer essa string e ir cortando o inicio verificando se essa substring começa com algum dos pedaços que `array2` tem.

Exemplo:

```js
const array1 = ['azxsdfghjkazxfgtfgt'];
const array2 = ['azx', 'sdf', 'ghjk', 'fgt'];

function extrair(string, arr) {
  var encontradas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    arr.forEach(function(match) {
      if (string.slice(i).indexOf(match) == 0) encontradas.push(match);
    });
  }
  return encontradas;
}

var array3 = extrair(array1[0], array2);
console.log(array3); // ['azx','sdf','ghjk', 'azx', 'fgt', 'fgt'];
```

Comment: oo cara era esse o resultado que eu queria, muuuuito obrigado, nessa função tem método que ainda eu vou me aprofundar nos estudos, mas só por esse código ele vai servir de base pra testes tanto para esses métodos que esta dento da função como pra outros, muito obrigado!